# Rails: attr_accessor doesn't show up when try to render as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, oop, model

In my application I have a model that is below;

```
class Init < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :clientAvailability
  attr_accessible :returnCode, :returnMessage, :tokenCode, :updateURL
end
```

In here when I've added the **attr_accessor** later on and when I try to apply **render json:  init** it doesn't show the **clientAvailability** property even though I've set it as;

```
init=Init.new
init.clientAvailability="3"
```

When I **debug** it I can see that it is set, but doesn't simply show up when I try to render it as json. What could be the thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is clientAvailability a column in the DB? If not, then I suppose it is the default way - to serialize only the DB attributes. But you can do:

```
render json: init, methods: [:clientAvailability]
```

to include clientAvailability attribute.