# How to send attr_accessor values in json render using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

In my ruby on rails program i have used attr_accessor. But while rendering json its not coming in the view.
My code is as follows

```
  @users.each do |user|
    user.entry_id= "QWER1234"
    user.save
  end
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render json: {logs: @users, iTotalRecords: @users.total_entries, iTotalDisplayRecords: @users.total_entries} }
  end
```

If i check in view my attr_accessor entry_is is not available. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Hey. Sorry user.save is not needed for such accessor methods. The value will exist till the objects life cycle.

Comment: Ya. i know that. there could be some thing in render json

Comment: Inside controller if i loop through the @user , i am able to get the entry_id. But in view i am not

Comment: check here the reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597844/rails-attr-accessor-doesnt-show-up-when-try-to-render-as-json

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435768/cannot-access-attr-accessor-defined-variables

Comment: my case is different. I dont know how to add like that

Comment: Would this work `format.json { render json: {logs: @users.to_json(methods: ['entry_id']), iTotalRecords...}`?  See first comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055786/specifying-attributes-of-a-rails-object-passed-into-a-json-object?answertab=active#tab-top).